# GCP - Windows Activation

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I'm using a GCP-VM instance with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Edition installed normally, suddenly Windows is not activated more and i can't do it.

I tried to active windows in control panel, but i had the message below:

[image]

In my revenue i have a fee for windows license, so i don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to GCP documents [click here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances#routing_requirements) and [click here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances#kms-server) , you need to recheck configure routes and firewall rules in your VPC network to allow access to kms.windows.googlecloud.com (35.190.247.13).

Furthermore I attached this document [click here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#licensing) , as I think it will be useful regarding your request and you will be able to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I use the commands `cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms 35.190.247.13:1688` and `cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato` and it's work, thanks!